# Flutter: ChangeNotifier listener get's refreshed with old value sometimes before getting the new one

Tags: android, flutter, dart, riverpod

I am building a table_calendar widget, on which I want to select multiple days and keep them in firestore. (Selected days are green, everything else white)

[image]

I get the values from firestore via stream provider and use ChangeNotifier to read those values where I need to and I use _selectedDays.addAll (from table_calendar) to add all the values onto the calendar. My problem is that sometimes, when I try to deselect a day, it get's removed from firebase, but the ChangeNotifier listener gets refreshed with the old value before it gets refreshed with the new value, meaning that the day remains selected, even though it shouldn't be.
When I am halting a test listener.

```
final events = watch(todoChangeNotifierProvider).todos;
```

**I can see that 60-70% of the times it gets the new value, but sometimes it refreshes with the old one, screwing up the table_calendar ui.**

**Why does this happen?**

I have the provider declared globally

```
final todoChangeNotifierProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose<TodosProvider>((ref) {
  return TodosProvider();
});
```

And TodosProvider looks like this

```
class TodosProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  List<Todo> _todos = [];

  void setTodos(List<Todo> todos) {
    _todos = todos;
  }
```

I am setting the Change Notifier value inside the stream, so if something changes it gets updated.

EDIT: More code
Setting the ChangeNotifer with stream value

```
Widget build(BuildContext context,ScopedReader watch) {
    final todoProvider = watch(todoChangeNotifierProvider);
    //Todo? currentTodo = Todo();
    final firebaseAuth = context.read(firebaseAuthProvider);
    final todoStream = watch(todoStreamProvider(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('DASHBOARD'),
      ),
      body: todoStream.when(
          data: (data) {
            final currentTodo = data;
            todoProvider.setTodos(currentTodo);
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 55),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, //Center Column contents horizontally,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, //Center Row contents horizontally,
                        children: [Text('${currentUser!.loginStreak}',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)), Icon(Icons.local_fire_department, size: 40,color: Color(0xFFFD8787),), Text('DAILY ACTIVITY STREAK', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),)],),
                    ],
                  ),
                 Column(
                   children: [
                     TodoListWidget(editAllowed: true, currentUser: currentUser,)
                   ],
                 )
```

Reading the provider

```
class TodoListWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final UserData? currentUser;
  final editAllowed;
  TodoListWidget({this.editAllowed, this.currentUser});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
        final todoProvider = watch(todoChangeNotifierProvider);
        final todos = todoProvider.todos;
        return todos.isEmpty
...
```

selecting the day, marking it, and updating firebase

```
void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
setState(() {
if (_selectedDays.contains(selectedDay)) {
        docRef.update({
          'calendarEvents': FieldValue.arrayRemove([selectedDay])
        });
        userPointsRef.update({'points': FieldValue.increment(-1)});
        habitPointsRef
            .update({'daysTrackedThisWeek': FieldValue.increment(-1)});
        _selectedDays.remove(selectedDay);
      } else {
        //INCREMENTS POITNS AND DAYS TRACKED ON SELECTED DAY

        docRef.update({
          'calendarEvents': FieldValue.arrayUnion([selectedDay])
        });
        userPointsRef.update({'points': FieldValue.increment(1)});
        habitPointsRef.update({'daysTrackedThisWeek': FieldValue.increment(1)});
        _selectedDays.add(selectedDay);
      }
    });
enter code here
```

To try and paint a better picture.
I get the table_calendar values from firebase via a stream.
I set the values to a ChangeNotifier
I read the ChangeNotifier (But it seems, that 40% of the time, when a new value comes it first refreshes with the old value, before it gets the new one (that messes up the ui)

This is how I set the values for table_calendar selected days
in TodoWidget

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _selectedDays.addAll(widget.todo!.calendarEvents);
```

The values come from TodoListWidget

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `notifyListeners()` after setting `_todos`?

Comment: I had it, but I get a runtime error with it, and the problem persists. I am watching for changes with watch already.

Comment: You haven't included the part of your code that is responsible for the error. Can you please add more context to this question?

Comment: Added more code and context

Answer (score 0):

You *have* to use `notifyListeners` with `ChangeNotifier`. When you are watching the provider, it only knows to pick up a new value if `notifyListeners` is called.

The reason you are getting a runtime error when doing so is that you are triggering an update during the initial build.

In your ChangeNotifier, add the call to `notifyListeners`:

```dart
void setTodos(List<Todo> todos) {
  _todos = todos;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

In your widget code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context,ScopedReader watch) {
  final firebaseAuth = watch(firebaseAuthProvider);
  final todoStream = watch(todoStreamProvider(firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid));
  
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('DASHBOARD'),
    ),
    body: todoStream.when(
      data: (currentTodo) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          context.read(todoChangeNotifierProvider).setTodos(currentTodo);
        });
        return SingleChildScrollView(...);
}
```

The PostFrameCallback does exactly what it sounds like - delays the code from being run until the next frame, which will eliminate the runtime error you were facing.

Comment: Tried this and now it constantly needs 2 clicks to clear selectedDay
1st one removes from database, 2nd one removes from UI.